# Incorrect output when finding second smallest integer

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, while-loop

The following code only occasionally returns the right value, and it seems completely random when it does and when it doesn't. Pointers please?

```
/*This program takes a series of integers as user input
 * and returns the second smallest amongst them to the
 * console. 
 * 
 * For reasons unknown to the programmer, ending user 
 * input with Ctrl-D only works occasionally. If Ctrl-D
 * fails, enter any character(s) to the console and press 
 * enter. Make sure the dummy characters are separated 
 * from any integers with whitespace. The program should 
 * execute normally, ignoring the dummy character(s).
 * 
 * Written by xxxxxx, w45-2013*/

package secondSmallest;

import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SecondSmallest {

    PrintStream out;
    Scanner in;

    SecondSmallest() {
        out = new PrintStream(System.out);
        in = new Scanner(System.in);
    }

    void start() {
        out.printf("Enter 3 or more positive integers, seperate with whitespace. End input with Ctrl-D.%nInteger input:");
        int smallest, secondSmallest = 2147483647, nextInt;
        smallest = in.nextInt();
        while (in.hasNextInt()) {
            nextInt = in.nextInt();
            if (nextInt < smallest) {
                secondSmallest = smallest;
                smallest = nextInt;
            }
        }
        out.printf("The second smallest integer is %d", secondSmallest);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SecondSmallest().start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Incidently the way you're using this program is slightly strange (Ctrl-D!) just hit enter after every integer and any other key + enter to terminate

Comment: For completeness: `if (in.hasNextInt()) { smallest = in.nextInt();`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be that you're missing the second case for when only the second smallest number needs to be updated:

```
if (nextInt < smallest) {
    secondSmallest = smallest;
    smallest = nextInt;
} else if (nextInt < secondSmallest) {
    secondSmallest = nextInt;
}
```